# What is the size of the Section vector of certain data type in wasm binary?

Tags: binary, webassembly, wasmtime

I am reading [this](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/modules.html#custom-section) docs. I have doubt about the content of the vector of the sections in binary. For eg Table Section [here](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/modules.html#table-section). How many items of type tabletype can be present in that `vector<tabletype>`. Is it **0,1 and more** or   **0(not present) and 1 (only one present)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table section is made of vector of tables: `vec(table)`. Each `table` has one `tabletype`. From [here](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/conventions.html#binary-vec):

```
Vectors are encoded with their u32 length followed 
by the encoding of their element sequence.
```

This means that a module might have [0..2^32) `tables`, each with its own`tabletype`. That said, it is expected, that some ["reasonable" limitation](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/appendix/implementation.html) is placed on the number of tables (and other objects) that a program is willing to load.

If there are no tables, the section might be [omitted](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/modules.html#binary-section):

```
Every section is optional; an omitted section is equivalent 
to the section being present with empty contents.
```

This makes a total of three ways to have no tables: no section; empty section; section with a zero length `tables` vector.

As usual, when de-serializing (parse) one might expect all cases, but the when serializing (generate) it is better to have the minimum number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks..Just a question does the same apply for other sections as well like memory section, global section, function section etc?

Comment: The minimum textual serialization of a module is (module). Yes, you may omit it all, even the module name. The binary and the text serializations shall be equivalent.